# How to limit SQL query results for any query from code

Tags: sql

I need to write a function in my app, that gets as input SQL query and limits the results to 10 rows.
It needs to work with as many edge cases as possible.
What I had in mind is (Pseudo code):

```
func String limitQuery(String query) {
    if (query.endsWith(';'))
        // TODO remove trailing semicolon
    }
    query = query + " LIMIT 10;";
    return query;
}
```

There are many edge cases that this code is missing (like what if the query already has `LIMIT` at the end).
I am looking for suggestions how to do it the right way and cover as many edges cases as possible that will also work with as many types of relational databases possible, and for very complicated queries.

Comment: Not 100%, but remove any instances of `LIMIT [number]` from the query, wrap the query in parentheses, and then add `LIMIT 10`. The problem: if the query uses nested limits, it could break inner limits.

Comment: Just like you are checking for `;` you can check if the query text contains `limit` and add if necessary. do all your queries already work cross-database? Very unlikely but if so you'll need to know which database engine is being used, `limit` is rdbms-specific.

Comment: Another way, apart mentioned ones, you can just fetch maximum of 10 rows in select, so you dont change slq, but code itself. Or limit iterations to 10, while looping.

Comment: I'd wrap the entire user query in a CTE and then add the limit like this: WITH CTE AS( ...users sql query...) SELECT * FROM CTE LIMIT 10;  if there's already a limit it shouldnt hurt anything. You would still strip out any semicolons

Comment: It's probably not safe to do that, for example if the query already used a CTE, you can't nest multiple `with` clauses

Comment: I tested it, and it does work with nested `WITH` clauses